# Jcart how do I add a select box to manipulate price

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using Jcart, and I want a drop down that will manipulate the price.

Right now the price in the form is being populated by a database value.

```
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row_RecordSetBottle['price']; ?>" />
<h4>Price:<?php echo $row_RecordSetBottle['price']; ?></h4>
```

I want the price to be manipulated by a drop down so they can select additional features that would cost more, thus reflecting more to the price. For example, the default of the drop down would be the original price, then second selection would be +$5 to the price, the third +$10 to the original price.

The biggest thing that is making it hard for me to wrap my head around this problem is that this product is not alone on the page.

More specifically, I have the products being populated in this way

```
   <ul id="product">
      <?php do { ?>
            <form method="post" action="" class="jcart">
        <li>
            <p>  

            <select name="add" id="add" >
                <option value="<?php echo $row_RecordSetBottle['price'] ?>">
                    <?php echo $row_RecordSetBottle['price'] ?></option>
                <option value="<?php echo $row_RecordSetBottle['price'] + 5.00 ?>">
                    <?php echo $row_RecordSetBottle['price'] + 5.00 ?></option>
                <option value="<?php echo $new3=$row_RecordSetBottle['price'] + 10.00 ?>">
                    <?php echo $row_RecordSetBottle['price'] + 10.00 ?></option>
            </select>

            <!--NOW I NEED THE NEW PRICE TO SHOW HERE -->
                 <h4>Price:<?php echo  $row_RecordSetBottle['price'] ?></h4>
            <!--NOW I NEED THE NEW PRICE TO SHOW HERE -->
                 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row_RecordSetBottle['price']; ?>" /> 

                 <div></div>                        
                    <input type="submit" name="my-add-button" value="add to cart" class="button" />
              </p>
            </
          <?php } while ($row_RecordSetBottle = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordSetBottle)); ?>
    </ul>
</div><!-- End content_products -->
```

i need to show the price, the new price that the select box made.

the loop is making it impossible for me to do anything...

I want all of the products to have this drop down feature

Answer (score 0):

Where you display the other details for the product add in the creation of a select list :

```
$currentprice = $row_RecordSetBottle['price'];

<select>
  <option value="<?php echo $currentprice ?>"><?php echo $currentprice ?></option>
  <option value="<?php echo $currentprice + 5 ?>"><?php echo $currentprice + 5 ?></option>
  <option value="<?php echo $currentprice + 10 ?>"><?php echo $currentprice + 10 ?></option>
</select>
```

A caveat - `$currentprice` must to be numeric

Comment: ok the problems here is this is there are 30 products in this page with the value  $row_RecordSetBottle['price'];...  I cant get $currentprice = $row_RecordSetBottle['price']; to work at all  but i can do <?php echo $row_RecordSetBottleCap['price'] + 10.00 ?> and it works but now i need to use this value and the new price

Comment: @design im not sure your comment is complete ? The answer i gave should point you in the right direction - it wont be a fully working solution......

Comment: sorry first time I have used this site. kinda confusing with the commenting

Comment: You have a while loop - you can put the code above within the while loop - it means it will get executed for each row in the database - to use the new price you need to look what happens when the form is submitted and ensure you read the selection option from the drop down list as the price